# mvn archetype:generate command not working

Tags: java, maven

I tried to run **mvn archetype:generate** command on ubuntu but it is not working. It is showing some error.

Here I am attaching the error.

> [WARNING] Error injecting:
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder
>   com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the
>   following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuilder
>   was bound.   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder
>
> 1 error
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException
>   (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision
>   (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get
>   (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get (ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get (SingletonScope.java:168)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get
>   (PlexusRequirements.java:250)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty (ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers (BeanInjector.java:52)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers (MembersInjectorImpl.java:160)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:124)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision
>   (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$CycleActivator.onProvision (BeanScheduler.java:230)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get
>   (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get (ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get (SingletonScope.java:168)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container (MavenCli.java:676)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:282)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:282)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:406)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) [WARNING] Error injecting:
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven com.google.inject.ProvisionException:
>   Unable to provision, see the following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuilder
>   was bound.   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder   at
>   ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules:
>   org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule ->
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven
>
> 1 error
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException
>   (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision
>   (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$CycleActivator.onProvision (BeanScheduler.java:230)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision
>   (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get
>   (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get (ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get (SingletonScope.java:168)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container (MavenCli.java:676)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:282)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:282)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:406)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) [ERROR] Error executing Maven. [ERROR]
>   com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the
>   following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuilder
>   was bound.   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder   at
>   ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules:
>   org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule ->
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven   at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent:
>   null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule ->
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.Maven
>
> 1 error
>         role: org.apache.maven.Maven   roleHint:  [ERROR] Caused by: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuilder
>   was bound.   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder   at
>   ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules:
>   org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule ->
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven   at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent:
>   null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule ->
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)   while locating
>   org.apache.maven.Maven
>
> 1 error

Here is the attached image to check that maven is responding on **mvn --version**.

[image]

Environment Variables are attached here:

[image]

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: I am using Apache Maven 3.6.3

Comment: Just try `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate` instead? (BTW: Hoping you are running on plain command line?

Comment: No sir, its not working. It is giving the same error and yes I am running the commands on the command line.

Comment: Two things. First try `mvn --version` and post the output please second: Does your environment contains variables like `M2*` or `MAVEN*` etc. ?

Comment: Sir I have edited the question and included the image. Now you can check it out. And sir can you please tell me how can I show the environment variables to you?

Comment: Just use `printenv | grep -i "^M"` that will show all variables which start with `m` ...

Comment: Yes sir I have attached the image displaying environment variables. You can see that in the question.

Comment: Sorry @khmarbaise sir, to knock you again but do you able to find the solution?

Comment: Sir I am able to solve my issue. Its now working.

Comment: Then please answer your own question to document the solution...